# sort an array and loop its content by desc date after selecting an option in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How i can sort an array by desc date after selecting the specific option in a select element in React. 
import React, {Component} from 'react';

```
class App extends Component {
/* constructor … 
componentDidMount() {
/* fetch data…. Into an array for example fetchData[].id 
fetchData[0].Id: {"2017-01-01"}
fetchData[1].id: {"2017-01-05"}
   */
this.setState({fetchData: array});
},

change(event) {
this.setState={
var sorted_dates = fetchData.sort((a,b) => {
return new Date(a.id).getTime() - 
new Date(b.id).getTime()
}).reverse(););
},

render(){
return(
<div>
<select id="lang" onChange={this.change} value=>
<option value="{this.state.value1}">Date</option>
<option value="{this.state.value2}">Impact</option>
</select>
<div> {this.state.fetchData.map(campaign => <Widget data={campaign} />)}</div>
</div>
);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create new property in your components state called `sortBy` and keep value of select in that property and change order of dates based on that value.

```js
const Widget = props => {
  return (
    <div className="widget">
    <h3>{props.date} | {props.impact}</h3>
    </div>
    )
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {fetchData: [], sortBy: null}
    this.renderContent = this.renderContent.bind(this);
  }
  
  componentWillMount() {
    const dates = [{date: "2017-01-01", impact: 2}, {date: "2017-01-05", impact: 1}]
    this.setState({fetchData: dates})
  }
  
  change(event) {
    this.setState({sortBy: event.target.value});
  }
  
  renderContent() {
    let {fetchData, sortBy} = this.state;
    
    switch(sortBy) {
      case 'date':
      fetchData.sort((a, b) => Date.parse(b.date) - Date.parse(a.date))
      break;

      case 'impact':
      fetchData.sort((a, b) => b.impact - a.impact);
      break;
    }
    
    return fetchData.map((data, i) => <Widget key={i} {...data} />)
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
       <select id="lang" onChange={this.change.bind(this)}>
          <option value="date">Date</option>
          <option value="impact">Impact</option>
       </select>

        <div>{this.renderContent()}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById('app')
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately it only shows the dates not all the list of widgets which contain components and have dependent values and were transfered through the `{this.state.fetchData.map(campaign => <Widget data={campaign} />)}`    Can you please explain what that specific part do (date.date)? :  `return  <div key={i}>{date.date}</div>`

Comment: Altough my table `FetchData [ id: "2017-01-01", impact: {absolute_value: 6600}, outcome: {absolute_value: 0.229}.. ]`   it says: "Cannot read property 'absolute_value' of undefined"  in the lines   `{props.id} | {props.impact.absolute_value} | {props.outcome.absolute_value} |`.  Your first example was working it was just not sending the data from the widget component to it's child components

Answer (score 0):

You take your `array` of objects, containing the `date` property and run

```
 array.sort((a,b) => +new Date(b.date) - +new Date(a.date))
```

Swapping a and b results in ascending sort.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but the question was specifically about how I implement this only when the specific selection is selected. Do I have to set it as a new state? And then put it on specific tag?